# Android Facebook login fails without an exception, just "Sorry something went wrong"

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, facebook-login, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to implement Facebook login into my app, and I'm facing a very peculiar issue, where the login process begins, fails with a very cryptic message and no exception is thrown on my app's side so I don't know what's going on.

I'm suspecting there is something to do with me using a `DialogFragment` for my login process, and the Facebook `LoginButton` is part of this `DialogFragment` instead of a normal fragment or activity. I add the login button in my XML:

```
 <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/loginFacebookButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin_double"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_margin_double"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/default_margin"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:background="@drawable/rounded_blue_bg"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/default_margin_double"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/loginOrLayout" />
```

And I add the callbacks in code, in my `onCreateDialog`

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.FullscreenDialog)

    val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.fragment_login, null)

    //FB Login callback manager
    val callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()
    val fbLoginButton = view.loginFacebookButton
    fbLoginButton.fragment = this
    fbLoginButton.setPermissions(listOf("name", "email", "public_profile"))
    fbLoginButton.loginBehavior = LoginBehavior.NATIVE_WITH_FALLBACK
    fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
            object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                    fbLoginSuccessful(loginResult)
                }

                override fun onCancel() {}

                override fun onError(exception: FacebookException) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "onError: Failed to login with FB.", exception)
                    loginFailed(exception.localizedMessage)
                }
            })

    return dialog
}
```

When I press the login button, I get a loading ProgressBar, then the Facebook app opens, I tap on my account, and then after some more loading, I get this screen:

[image: Facebook Login Error]

I've followed the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/) but I cannot seem to get it to work. Any help is greatly appreciated. I even printed the key hash from within my code as mentioned [here in the documnetation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/advanced), and I have the correct hashes ion the developer console, but still get the errors. Thank you

Comment: Do you have the facebook app downloaded in your phone?

Comment: Yes, I tried both with it installed, and without, still getting the same error, in the FB app, or the webview fallback... It must be some parameter i'm passing in, but i cant figure out what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I’m getting the same error message

Comment: @DanAbnormal Unfortunately no, I've also posted to the facebook developer support forum and I got no reply there as well. I have an app that is ready for production and this is the only thing that is keeping us back... I'll try to create a dummy app and use the exact same steps to add FB login and see if it works or not. If you figure something out, please let me know.

Comment: @DanAbnormal I tried again today, and it finally worked. I'm unsure if it really was a problem on the facebook's side, please check my answer below for more info.

Comment: @LucasP. Thanks for this. I will check it out!

Comment: @LucasP. Worked for me too, but only on different device. Problem still there when trying on Android tablet. Not sure what to make of this; is it the facebook app settings on the device or the device itself?

Comment: @LucasP.  Actually, it did not work after all. But however, after skipping the fb login button and going with custom UIButton and LoginManager instead, everything works fine!

Comment: @DanAbnormal I've also tried the "Custom button + LoginManager" way about a week ago and I was getting the same error. Since yesterday both methods seem to work... Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I was missing the following in my fragment:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

However, It might have not been related, since the error was being thrown before the actual FB activity returned, so maybe it was an internal facebook error that has been fixed.

Good luck to anyone facing similar issues, the support for the FB SDK is virtually non existent.

Comment: Still getting this error! I have this override method as well.

Comment: I still haven't figured out what the problem was (if it was on my side or on Facebook's). What I did though is create a new dummy app that had the same structure as my `LoginFragment` (meaning I was using the Navigation Component and a DialogFragment) and implemented the FB Login button there, which it worked. Then after removing it and adding it back to my original project, it worked again. I'm not sure what's going on there.

Comment: I found the issue with my code. Turns out I was send permission "email" in capital letters (EMAIL). Had to check each and every line of my code multiple times. It sucks that they don't send a precise error message.

Comment: you don't need it if use androidx libraries

Answer (score 1):

Edit to add Sourabh comment: "I found the issue with my code. Turns out I was send permission "email" in capital letters (EMAIL). Had to check each and every line of my code multiple times. It sucks that they don't send a precise error message. –"

Following the comment of Sourabh, I fixed this error checking the permissions in the logIn facebook function. Double check your permissions and if it doesn't work, try to send just the email, to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a permission issue, I added "mobile" also in Permissions and this error appeared. After removing it everything seems to work perfectly.